# How to "correctly" create an object which inherits from Element?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, dom

I am writing an HTML5 application that involves a lot of XML manipulation, part of this manipulation involves comparing the versions of two different XML Elements.

What I need is for every Element, Attr, and TextNode (all of which inherit from Node, AFAIK) object that gets created to have associated version information, but still be able to behave like a normal Element, Attr, or TextNode.  The current working solution I am using to store the version information, is the following:

```
Node.prototype.MyAppAnnotation = {
        Version : null
};
```

Now, I understand that augmenting built-in types is considered bad form, but beyond this technique, I'm at a loss for how to get the desired functionality.  I don't think I can encapsulate the Node in a wrapper because I need the Node related properties and functions exposed on the wrapper.  I might be able to write some sort of pass-through functions for the wrapper, but that seems really clunky.

I feel that because the app I'm writing is an HTML5 app, and as such only has to run on the most modern browsers (all of which support the augmentation of built-ins), makes this technique appropriate.  Also, by providing a sufficiently obscure name to my augmentation object, I can avoid all naming collisions (except for intentional collisions).  I've also explored inheritance-based solution using Google's Closure library.  However, it appears that because Element, Node and TextNode don't have direct constructors (i.e. they're created off of a Document object), this technique will not work either.

I was wondering if someone could either a) recommend an elegant way of achieving this effect without augmenting Element, or b) provide a compelling reason for why I shouldn't break the "don't augment built-ins" rule in this case.

Many Thanks,
Jarabek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is theoretically valid, but there's a weird feeling I get when reading about it.

First of all - you don't have to augment any prototypes. If you just do `somedomnode.myweirdname='foo'` it will become a field of that object. That's what javascript does ;)
So when there is no version you'll get undefined instead of null.

**But,** if you want to add more functionality or wrap dom node in anything - there's a bit of history of doing that. Most of that history is dominated by stuff like jQuery :)

Just create an object that has a field containing the node. And then you can access it really simply:

`myobject.node`

And create the object with some constructor or just factory function:

`var myobject = createDomNodeWrapper(domnode)`

Comment: A question about your first example: somedomnode.myweirdname='foo'; Wouldn't I have to do this every time I create a Node? I create Elements, Nodes, and Attrs in several different spots in my app, and it seems that by modifying the prototype, I can save that hassle.

Comment: then I don't fully understand your versioning idea, because if you add a field to the prototype I assumed you would want to set the field to some value (for each element). If you'd set the value on prototype once and change it later on the prototype again, you change it everywhere (including the older instances). So how was that suposed to save any hassle if you either set it for all elements or just put the same value on all?

Comment: I see what you're getting at.  Your explanation makes a lot more sense now.  Thanks.